# Count matches at the end of a string

Tags: javascript

I want to count the number of occurrences of a string at the end of the string.  I want it to ignore occurrences that are not at the end and I want it to return zero if there are none.

terminal string to find: "-1"

```
e.g. string = 1
// 0
e.g. string = 1-1
// 1
e.g. string = 1-1-1
// 2
e.g. string = 1-2-1
// 1
e.g. string = 1-2-1-2-1
// 1
e.g. string = 2-1-1-1-1
// 4
e.g. string = 1-1-2
// 0
```

I want it to count all of the occurrences at the end of the string, not just the occurrences anywhere in the string.

I tried:

```
var occurrences = string.match(/(-1)*$/).length;
```

I have a JS Fiddle here: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wy5magzj/1/)

It returns "2", no matter what my string.

Comment: What is the result you are getting? (I guess it is `4` for `1-1-1`, not `2`, because you use the string length, not computing the amount of tokens)

Comment: My JSFiddle returns 2 no matter what string I use.

Comment: It's because `match` returns an array which always have 2 elements, the matched string and grouping operator (the one inside parentheses in regex`()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work on the first element of the returned array:

```
string.match(/(-1)*$/)[0].length/2
```

Find the length of first element which is the matched string of `"-1"` at the end and divide by 2 since the string `"-1"` is of length `2`.

To quote from MDN [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> **Return value**
>
> If the string matches the expression, it will return an Array
>   containing the entire matched string as the first element, followed by
>   any results captured in parentheses. If there were no matches, null is
>   returned.

```js
function count() {
  console.log(string.match(/(-1)*$/)[0].length / 2)
}

var string = "1"
// 0
count();

string = "1-1"
// 1
count();

string = "1-1-1"
// 2
count();

string = "1-2-1"
// 1
count();

string = "1-2-1-2-1"
// 1
count();

string = "2-1-1-1-1"
// 4
count();

string = "1-1-2"
// 0
count();
```

Comment: It is important for people reading this question to see the way that match works and the need for looking at the correct length (match[0]) and the impact of my string length.  Thank you for the help, and thank you for bringing attention to the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Walk backwards and count?

```js
var string = "2-1-1-1-1";
var find =   "-1";
var match =  0;

for (var i = string.length; i >= 0; i -= find.length) {
  if (string.substr(i - find.length, find.length) == find)
    match++;
  else
    break;
}

console.log("="+match)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String#match to find the chain of `-1` that reaches the end, then split by `-1`, and get the length -1. When you split an a string of `-1-1-1` you'll get an array with four items. Now we can extract the length, and reduce it by one.

```js
function m(str) {
  return str.match(/(-1)*$/g)[0].split(-1).length - 1;
}

console.log(m('1')) // 0
console.log(m('1-1')) // 1
console.log(m('1-1-1')) // 2
console.log(m('1-2-1')) // 1
console.log(m('1-2-1-2-1')) // 1
console.log(m('2-1-1-1-1')) // 4
console.log(m('1-1-2')) // 0
```

Comment: Can you please a little more of what the end of this code is doing:  '.split(-1).length - 1?

Comment: This also works well.  I chose the above one as my solution because of how it explains how match() works, including why we need match()[0].  You clearly understand it also and this solution seems equally useful.  It was hard to choose between the two.

Comment: @Thomas - you chose well. I like his solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Non regex version:

```
var occurences = 0;
string.split("-1").reduceRight((exit, space) => {
  if(exit || space) return true;
  occurences++;
  return false;
}, false);
```

Comment: I clicked on your link.  It is not giving the correct results.  It should only be counting those at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This runs Ok for all of your tested values

```js
function countOnesAtTheEnd(s){
var array = s.split("-");

var count = 0;
for(var i =1; i<array.length; i++)
{ 
if(array[i] =="1"){
 count++;
 }
 else count = 0;

}
console.log(count);
}
countOnesAtTheEnd("1");
countOnesAtTheEnd("1-1");
countOnesAtTheEnd("1-1-1");
countOnesAtTheEnd("1-2-1");
countOnesAtTheEnd("1-2-1-2-1");
countOnesAtTheEnd("2-1-1-1-1");
countOnesAtTheEnd("1-1-2");
```